# Append value to an existing key in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting key-value (text) data in chunks and need to create a new JSON obj without duplicating the keys in the resulting file.For e.g.

```js
var jsonData = {};
var incoming = {
  "p1": "value1",
  "p2": "value2",
  "p3": "value3",
  "p1": "value4"
};

for (var key in incoming) {
  if (key in jsonData) {
    key = key + p[key]; //append text value to existing key value
    jsonData[key].push(incoming[key]);
  } else {
    jsonData[key] = [incoming[key]];
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

Desired output:

```
{"p1":"**value1value4**","p2":"value2","p3":"value3"}
```

How do  I can get the desired output?

Comment: Your `incoming` object is not valid. You can't have duplicate keys in an object.

Comment: `incoming` does ***NOT*** have "two same keys". Objects *cannot* have duplicate keys. When that is encountered, you just get one. Usually the latter but you might run into the former in some edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate `p1` keys in the incoming object. You should change `incoming` to a format that allows duplicates, like a 2-dimensional array.

Then when you're creating the result, use string concatenation rather than pushing onto an array.

```js
var jsonData = {};
var incoming = [
  ["p1", "value1"],
  ["p2", "value2"],
  ["p3", "value3"],
  ["p1", "value4"]
];

for (var [key, value] of incoming) {
  if (key in jsonData) {
    jsonData[key] += value;
  } else {
    jsonData[key] = value;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```